# copy whole data from closed excel sheet and paste as a value and formatting to active workbook

Tags: excel, vba

ı have a problem about copy and pasting data as a value to the active workbook.

ı use this VBA code but this code paste data with formulas. but ı dont want formulas. ı want just values.

here is my code.

```
Sub CopySheetFromClosedWB()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open("D:\A\B\C.xlsx")
    closedBook.Sheets("SYS").Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    closedBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: copy > pastespecial - values ?

Comment: Yes you are right, ı try but cant do it :) would you help me about code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Values

- s - Source, d - Destination

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheetFromClosedWB()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open("D:\A\B\C.xlsx")
    swb.Worksheets("SYS").Copy Before:=dwb.Sheets(1)
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    With dwb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    'dwb.save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your coding . ı try immediately but there is an error like this: Run timr error 1004 application-difined or object defined error.

Comment: also datas come as formulas not as values

Comment: I can't produce this type of error. It's working fine on my end. Which line is highlighted (in yellow) when the error occurs?

Comment: no lines is getting yellow but when process finished , error comes to screen. also datas come with formulas. ı really need help.

Comment: Could you share your workbook or at least some description of your data (formulas) or screenshots since it's working on my end?